# How to randomly select rows from a Spark dataframe while a condition based on a column must holds too

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let say we have a Spark dataframe df with a column col where the values in this column are only 0 and 1. How can we select all rows where col==1 and also 50% of rows where col==0? The 50% population with col==0 should be randomly selected.

The sample method allows random selection of 50% of rows but no other condition can be imposed.

The solution that I currently have is as follows which seems a bit ugly to me. I wonder if there is a better solution.

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df = df.withColumn('uniform', F.rand())
    df = df.filter((df.uniform<0.5) | (df.col==1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't guarantee exactly 50%, but it should suffice given a large enough data set.

`df.where($"col" == 1 or rand() > rand())`

note: This will return a different set of random rows each time the dataframe/dataset is calculated. To remedy this, add the `rand() > rand()` qualification as a column in the DF, i.e. `df.withColumn("lucky", rand() > rand())`